# Specify base package in protobuf compilation in golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I've got golang package `github.com/user/protoapp`, in this package I have folder `proto` containing protobuf files.

```
github.com/user/protoapp
|-proto
|-proto/app1
|-proto/app2
```

proto files in `app1` and `app2` have corresponing packages `app1` and `app`;

Proto file from `proto/app1` is importing file from `proto/app2` like `import "app2/messages.proto";` after compillation in `app1.pb.go` it becomes `import app2` and `protoapp` fails to compile. How do I make imports in `*.pb.go` files become `import "github.com/user/protoapp/proto/app2"` rather than `import "app2"`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your import in your proto a fully qualified path like in Go:

instead of `import "app2/messages.proto";`

try `import "github.com/user/protoapp/proto/app2/messages.proto";`

Answer (score 0):

Never specify the half path "/app2/messages.proto" it won't be work.

1. Specify the full import name

```
import "github.com/user/protoapp/proto/app2/messages.proto";
```

and

2. Do define with the package name

```
//if we does'nt add package we define it will show error
package messagedata;
```